# Single Sign On (SSO) from desktop app and web app

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

Let's say I have an Angular web application that authenticates users in the Azure AD using MSAL: [tuturial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular)

Is there any way so that when a user is authenticated in a desktop app that an organization is using, for example Microsoft Outlook, it will do SSO on the Angular web app. So far, SSO to other web apps seem to work. However, not between desktop apps and web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is practically not possible currently. Please raise user voice [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) .

**Note:**  As long as the same browser is used, it should achieve SSO.

Comment: Are you saying it is not possible with Angular using MSAL only? Or is not possible to SSO with desktop apps and web applications in general?

Comment: It is not possible to SSO between desktop apps and web applications in general